# Ripleys K not plotting correctly?

Tags: r-sp, spatstat

I am doing point pattern analysis using the package spatstat and ran Ripley's K (spatstat::Kest) on my points to see if there is any clustering. However, it appears that not all the lines that should appear in the graph (kFem) have plotted. For example, the red line (Ktrans) stops at around x=12 and the green line (Kbord) doesn't appear at all. I would appreciate any insights as to how to interpret this and if there might be a bug.

[image: Kest]

Here is my study window. It is an irregular shape because I am analyzing a point pattern along a transect line.

[image: Owin]

And here is a density plot of my point pattern:

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer a bit based on this new information. I hope you find it useful. In conclusion: There is no bug, it is just the very elongated observation windows that makes it impossible to calculate some estimates at larger distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely (but not impossible) that there is a simple bug in `Kest` that causes this, since this particular function has been tested intensively by many users. More likely you have a observation window that is irregular and there is a mathematical reason why the various estimates cannot be calculated at all distances. Please add a plot/summary of your point pattern so we have knowledge of the observation window (or even better give access to the observation window).

Furthermore, to manually inspect the estimates of the K-function you can convert the function value (`fv`) object to a `data.frame` and print it:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(kFem)
head(dat, n = 10)
```

**Update:**

Your window is indeed very irregular and the explanation of why it is not producing some corrections at large distances. I guess your transect is only a few metres wide and you are considering distances up to 50m. The border correction can only be calculated for distances up to something like the half width of the transect.

Using `Kest` implies that you believe that your transect is a subset of a big **homogeneous** point process (of equal intensity everywhere and with same correlation structure throughout space). If that is true then `Kest` provides a sensible estimate of the unknown true homogeneous K-function. However, you provide a plot where you have divided the region into sections of high, medium and low intensity which doesn't agree with the assumption of homogeneity. The deviation from the theoretical Poisson line may just be due to inhomogeneous intensity and not actual correlation between points. You should probably only consider distances that are much smaller than 50 (you can set `rmax` when you call `Kest`).

Comment: Ok thank you, this helps a lot. To clarify, the High, Medium, and Low refer to densities of points belonging to one specific mark. Sampling was done evenly throughout the transect line, and I want to see if points belonging to that specific mark are clustered. Is there a different method you would recommend?